# AWS Batch on Fargate is not allocating the correct number of vCPUs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a web application offloading some resource-intensive tasks to AWS Batch, backed by Fargate.

It's a very simple setup - a single queue, a single job definition, and a single compute environment. The compute environment has a limit of `Maximum vCPUs: 128` and no Minimum vCPU.

The job complexity can be estimated upfront, so when the job is submitted, the application overrides `resourceRequirement` params to meet the estimated computing power needs. An equivalent CLI command would be:

```
aws batch submit-job \
  --job-name "test-job-1" \
  --job-definition "staging-batch" \
  --job-queue "staging-normal-priority" \
  --container-overrides 'resourceRequirements=[{type=VCPU,value=16},{type=MEMORY,value= 32768}]'
```

When I look at the job's container details in the web console, I can see the requested values: `vCPUs 16.0, Memory 32768`, which I assume means the command syntax is correct.

However, if I modify the job's `command` to curl `${ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4}` the returned response has `"Limits"=>{"CPU"=>2}` consistently. 1 CPU = 2 vCPUs, so I'd expect this to be `"CPU"=>8`. "Applied account-level quota value" for "Fargate On-Demand vCPU resource count" is 4000 (AWS default is 6), which should mean there's no quota-induced limiting.

Is there a way to get the desired number of vCPUs on Fargate, or does it mean AWS does not enough on-demand resources to allocate and is therefore consistently giving me 2CPUs?

**Edit:** If I run ruby's `Etc.nprocessors` (based on sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN) / sched_getaffinity ) I get 16, so I guess the 2 CPU limit Fargate box gives me is a red herring. Then the question becomes, why is it reporting the limit of 2?